# Scroll Down Address Bar Hiding Works Only After Page Refresh

Tags: jquery, html, css, mobile

I am working on a site: [bunpro.jp](http://www.bunpro.jp).

Ideally I want the address bar to hide when a user scrolls down while on mobile. This works when you visit the home page and I think that has to do with the fact that I am using FullpageJS with autoScrolling: false.

But on other pages without FullpageJS, it doesn't work normally. However, if you go to a page then refresh it, the address bar hides on scroll down. I have no idea what is causing it or why it is like that. I am also unsure what code I could post here that would be beneficial.

Please let me know if there is any code that I could post to help you help me or if you know what might be the source of this problem.

Thank you for your time!

Comment: what you have tried yet? show your code.

Comment: Is there any particular code that would be best? What part of the CSS HTML would be best?